# Dapp fundamental q about listening solidity events

Tags: dapps, php, websocket

Sol:
I created contract with events that are raised when is called some function.

Html fo:
Those functions are called via web3.js with abi and address - easy.

Backend (no js) asp or php:
I am not familiar with node.js so i am trying find something different.
I want store all events raised by my contract in relation database.
- and that's the point when i am completelly out ..how to catch every new raised event
1. Do I need own rpc node?
2. Do I need websocket - endpoint?
3. Must I send requests  to the EVM everytime or how can I get every raised event from my contract?
4. Exist somewhere some simple implementation or article that solved this fundamental question. Perhaps I am wrong and i don't understand how it works. please correct me.
ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a reactPHP based process to react on your contract events.

1. Do I need own rpc node? -> No it would work with a service like [infura.io](https://infura.io)
2. Do I need websocket - endpoint? -> No. Using http provider.
3. Must I send requests to the EVM everytime or how can I get every raised event from my contract? -> Kind of, but the [ethereum-php-eventlistener](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php-eventlistener) would do this for you
4. Exist somewhere some simple implementation or article that solved this fundamental question -> [here](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php-eventlistener#integration-with-truffle-and-contract-events)

Provided a short example here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/56247/852